# show modal dialog after closing it do ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

let's say , I got a modal dialog, which is embedded datepicker.

and ajax call.

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );           

$.ajax({
  url:'somewhere.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:something,

});
```

is there any way to wait ajax call, until dialog is closed?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the close option in the dialog definition:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
     close: function () {
            //ajax call here
     }
});
```

Comment: I have tried it ..
and @ firebug console it says "too much recursion"

Comment: This is a separate problem. You will likely get a "too much recursion" error if you are trying to do things with `$(this)` within the close function, or trying to update the dialog from within the ajax call.